# How to avoid one entry point while using split chunk in webpack4?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-redux, webpack-4

After Login in website, I am going to open project in different browser window. Hence, according to me, common.bundle.js would not load on either login window or detail website window.(Note: my understanding might be wrong)

In this context, to avoid above problem, I want to keep Login.bundle.js out of split chunk, so that web-pack creates normal bundle for login page. and creates all other bundle along with common.bundle.js for detail website window.

How can I do that, is their any special functionality to do that in web-pack 4?

My current code is following:

```
var config = {
    entry: {
        'Login': ['babel-polyfill', 'Login.js'],
        'MNO': ['babel-polyfill', 'MNO.js'],
        'JKL': ['babel-polyfill', 'JKL.js'],
        'GHI': ['babel-polyfill', 'GHI.js'],
        'DEF': ['babel-polyfill', 'DEF.js'],
        'ABC': ['babel-polyfill', '.ABC.js'],
        'vendorABC': ["jquery", "underscore", 'react', 'react-dom'] 
},
    mode: "development",
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
          cacheGroups: {
            default: false,
            commons: {
              test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
              name: 'vendor_app',
              chunks: 'initial',
              minChunks: 5
            }
          }
        }
    },

    output: {
        path: path.resolve('./'),
        filename: "[name].bundle.js"
    },
```

Comment: how is your login page route defined in your react app?

Comment: my whole application is build with aspx code, on some specific parts I am using react. For example, Login page is actually login.aspx file, weback generated login.bundle.js file is added to login.aspx using AddJSFile c# command.